# i want to transfer my ASP.NET MVC project to another server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, server, ssms

I want to transfer my ASP.NET MVC project to another server(obvious with different IP address). I transfer the published code there and also map with the same link through IIS (and stop that site from previous server). And also change the connection string with updated database details.

I get this error:

> Not Found
>   HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Kindly help.

Comment: your Domian will still configure to the old server IP. Without updating it you to new server, you will only see 404 or 500

Comment: If you browse NewServerName:PortNumber you can see your site ok?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to figure out whether the request is sending the request to the right server. So please ensure the domain is pointing to the correct IP. Please ensure accessing the website via IP and domain name are getting same response.

If you are sure the request is reaching the right server, then you should see the 404 error in Server IIS log. Please enable failed request tracing and IIS detailed error to find the sub-status code and exception code. 
If you see the 404 is returned from static file handler. Then please ensure IIS asp.net extension has been installed so that extensionless handler would help handle the MVC route URL.

If you have already installed asp.net extension. Please post more details and we may find the root cause.